# How does curry (==) work?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, currying

I understand that:

> (==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool

An example of application may be (==) 2 2, which result is True.

and that:

> uncurry (==) :: Eq b => (b, b) -> Bool.

An example of application may be uncurry (==) (2, 2), which result is True.

But I don't understand and visualize an example why:

> curry (==) :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> (a, b) -> Bool

Any help?

Thanks,
Sebastián

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `curry` is:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f = \x y -> f (x, y)
```

If we substitute that in:

```
\x y z -> (curry (==) x y) z
\x y z -> ((==) (x, y)) z    -- Function application
\x y z -> (==) (x, y) z      -- Remove parentheses (function application is left associative in Haskell, so they are unnecessary here)
\x y z -> (x, y) == z        -- Convert to infix
```

We can tell right away that `z` must be some kind of tuple as well, or else this last line wouldn't type check since both arguments of `==` must have the same type.

When we look at the definition of the tuple instance for `Eq`, we find

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) where
  (x, y) == (x', y') = (x == x') && (y == y')
```

(This isn't spelled out in the source code of the standard library, it actually uses the "standalone deriving" mechanism to automatically derive the instance for the `(Eq a, Eq b) => (a, b)` type. This code is equivalent to what gets derived though.)

So, in this case, we can treat `==` as though it has the type

```
(==) :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Bool
```

Both `x` and `y` must have types that are instances of `Eq`, but they don't need to be the *same* instance of `Eq`. For example, what if we have `12` and `"abc"`? Those are two different types but we can still use our function, since they are both instances of `Eq`: `(\x y z -> (x, y) == z) (12, "abc") (30, "cd")` (this expression type checks and evaluates to `False`).

Answer (score 9):

`==` can be used on tuples, that is you can write `(a1, b1) == (a2, b2)`.

In that case the type of `==` is specialized to `(Eq a, Eq b) => (a, b) -> (a,b) -> Bool`.

If you now apply `curry` to that type, you get `(Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> (a, b) -> Bool`.

Comment: Ok, but how you figured out that the == was applied to tuples?

Comment: @Seba Because `curry` expects a function whose first argument is a tuple.